# How to generate a hierarchy structure of table of contents in Birt

Tags: pdf, birt

I am using [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) to generate report in my application now. I can generate table of contents in my pdf [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) report like this **[Creating a table of contents](http://developer.actuate.com/be/documentation/ihub3/help/adg/adg42/index.html#page/ADG/iv-HowToCreateATOCEntry.html)** . But my data in formed in a tree structure,each record has an parent id to form a tree as below:
[image: The data structure of these data]
But when I set the table of contents of each record in the [birt](/questions/tagged/birt)**rptdesign** file,the generated pdf report is like this:
[image: Generated pdf report]

As we can see ,the table of contents in the pdf report is missing the hierarchy structure compared with the first picture.

**Now my question is how can I change the table of contents show in the second picture the same hierarchy structure as the first picture?** When I generate the pdf report file,I query all the data in the database and fetch it the report file.

PS:I found a same question here **[Hierarchical representation of TOC in report](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/20688-hierarchical-representation-of-toc-in-report/)** ,but still no answer for it.

Comment: Is this tree balanced, with a fix number of levels? Is is extracted from a database table having a recursive parent/child structure?

Comment: @Dominique it's not has a fixed number of levels,but it's extracted from a database table having a parent strucutre.